# mysql Insert error #1064

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have following table:

```
CREATE TABLE  `test123`.`orders` (
  `o_id` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `p_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `p_qty` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_price` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `o_price` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_charge` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_price` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `c_address` text NOT NULL,
  `c_pin` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_mobile` varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `c_email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `o_dt` date NOT NULL,
  `o_delivery_dt` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `o_remarks` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Trying to execute below Insert query:

```
insert into [orders] ([o_id],[p_id],[p_qty],[p_price],[o_price],[c_charge],[total_price],[c_name],[c_address],[c_pin],[c_mobile],[c_email],[o_dt],[o_delivery_dt],[o_remarks]) 
values('2016020002','PA001','1','900.00','900.00','','900.00','ABCD','my full address','123456','12345678','myabcd@abcd.com','2016-02-28 17:04:29','','');
```

On execution of this insert query getting error as "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[o_id],[p_id],[p_qty],[p_price],[o_price],[c_charge],[total_price],[c_name],[c_a' at line 1" error no: 1064.

Please help, unable find any syntax error here.

Comment: Drop all the `[` and `]` from the query - that looks like SQL-Server syntax. The keyword escape in mysql is backtics.

Comment: Thanks Kenney, Your suggestion worked like charm... Thanks a lot....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e16e3)  I have made some changes and now the schema runs. You were inserting `''` in c_charge which is not correct. Also `[]` tags are not required. Check out the link. 
Query is for Mysql db as the question tagged mysql.

```
  CREATE TABLE  orders (
  o_id varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  p_id varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  p_qty int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  p_price decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  o_price decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  c_charge decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  total_price decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  c_name varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  c_address text NOT NULL,
 c_pin varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  c_mobile varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  c_email varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  o_dt date NOT NULL,
  o_delivery_dt date DEFAULT NULL,
  o_remarks varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


insert into orders(o_id,p_id,p_qty,p_price,o_price,c_charge,total_price,c_name,c_address,c_pin,c_mobile,c_email,o_dt,o_delivery_dt,o_remarks) 
values('2016020002','PA001','1','900.00','900.00',null,'900.00','ABCD','my full address','123456','12345678','myabcd@abcd.com','2016-02-28 17:04:29',null,'');
```

Comment: Thanks DQLFiddle, Your suggestion worked like charm... and now added null value too .... Thanks a lot....